# Accessing Walmart API and setting up product mapping

Tags: flutter, walmart-api

To start: I'm completely new to working with APIs, so please bear with me.

My first question is related to getting access to the Walmart API. I see the example code to generate time stamp and signature. How do I run this file? I've looked at YouTube videos, the Walmart tutorial, and other posts in this forum and am still a little stuck.

Second, I'm guessing this file needs to be included in the actual application to continue to be able to access the products?

Third, my goal is to map only a subset of the product catalog for users of the app to view. Let's use 'soda' as an example. Is it the Taxonomy API I need to use? And how do I limit the available products a user can search?

Note: This will be implemented in a Flutter application, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Do post links to the relevant documentation if possible